# how to connect WiFi Direct Mobile phone to WiFi phone?

Tags: wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I was exploring regarding Wi-Fi Direct and came accross with conclusion that WiFi -certified devices can connect one-to-one or one-to-many and not all connected products need to be Wi-Fi Direct-certified. One Wi-Fi Direct enabled device can connect to legacy Wi-Fi certified devices.So by this we can conclude like if one device is having WiFi direct and other device is having Wifi one can easily connect to it.

I have following queries please help me to resolve.

1.This Wifi Direct is there in Android ICS onwards.So i am trying to connect WiFi Direct of my Samsung Note 2 having Jelly Bean with another Samsung Mobile Galaxy Y duos having Ginger Bread that only has WiFi but i am unable to detect? Can anyone help me in finding reason for this?

2.Another thing i studied is Wifi Direct device will become as access point means it will create an Ad-hoc network ? So why another Wifi devices are not detecting it?

Answer (score 0):

To find a wifi direct device in access point list of a normal wifi u need to create a wifi direct group. For this you need to first connect two wifi direct devices out of which one will act as a group owner and other as client. Once a group is created group owner act as a normal access point for legacy devices(Wifi devices).
Thus you need to create a Wifi Direct group first